# How to pass multiple arguments to rospy node through command line?

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a notation like this

```
 rosrun my_package my_node.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

That I can cun in the terminal, that will enable me to pass arguments to a ROS node which is implemented in python. So something like:

```
rosrun my_package read_topics.py arg1:='/topic1' arg2:='/topic2'
```

And be able to access those inside the python code like for example

```
subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(arg1, Bool, callback)
publisher = rospy.Publisher(arg2, Bool, queue_size=1)
```

How can I do that?

---

EDIT:

Based on the answers, the right approach is to pass arguments in a format

```
rosrun my_package my_node.py _one_topic:="/topic1" _another_topic:="/topic2" __name:="my_node_name"
```

and access the arguments inside the script as

```
publisher = rospy.Publisher(rospy.get_param('~one_topic'), Bool, queue_size=1)
subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(rospy.get_param('~another_topic'), Bool, callback)
```

The node name can be passed using a special parameter `__name`, because we need to know the node name prior to initializing the rospy node.

This works for me. Thank you both.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325992/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments-to-rospy-node-through-command-line?/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2019-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rosrun documentation](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#rosrun) should help here:

> It's also possible to pass a `~parameter` using the following syntax (replace the `~` with an `_`):
>
> ```
> rosrun package node _parameter:=value
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> rosrun my_package my_node _my_param:=value
> ```

Note:

> So something like:

> ```
> rosrun my_package read_topics.py arg1:='/topic1' arg2:='/topic2'
> ```

The exact syntax you're using in your example is actually the syntax you'd use for *remapping* topics from the command line with `rosrun`.

> And be able to access those inside the python code like for example

> ```
> subscriber = rospy.Subscriber(arg1, Bool, callback)
> ```

```
publisher = rospy.Publisher(arg2, Bool, queue_size=1)
```

that's not how this would work.

You'd access the parameters as *private parameters* ([Using Parameters in rospy](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters#Getting.2C_Setting.2C_and_Deleting_Parameters)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on 2019-06-17**:
@gvdhoorn So this approach works when I access the arguments after node initialization. But how can you pass the name of the node? You need to know the name before rospy node initialization.

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2019-06-17**:
You can set the node name via parameter with the `__name:=node_name` param (note the two underscores!) Then use `rospy.init("some_node_name")` After you initialize, you can get the node name with `rospy.get_name()` The value of `get_name()` depends on whether or not you set the `__name` from the commandline.